# Remove folder from working copy after removal from repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have removed a large data folder from our SVN repository using the `svndumpfilter` technique (dump repository, filter dump file, create new repository and re-import). That all went fine.

Now I'm trying to work out how to remove the folder from my working copy without having to do a fresh checkout.

If I delete it and then do an update it simply comes back (not sure from where, since it's not in the repo any more - I guess from within the depths of the .svn folder).

I expect it would cause problems if I deleted it locally and then did a commit so I haven't tried that (yet).

What's the best way to remove the local copy of the folder **other than doing a fresh checkout**?

Answer (score 0):

Just do an update - the folder will automatically be deleted.

Comment: Sadly no, as I said: **"If I delete it and then do an update it simply comes back"**

Comment: Not what I said - do not delete the folder: just do an update - the folder automatically gets deleted.  If you delete first then it recreates it but does not delete.  Also worth checking which version your working copy is at.  If it is at the same level as the deleted directory then it will not do anything.

Comment: No, doesn’t work. The update does nothing if the folder is still there.

Comment: I think your working copy is confused.  Try a clean.

Comment: I have tried a Clean Up actually and it made no difference. FWIW I have working copies on two machines and both have the same behaviour. It seems that a fresh check out may be the only solution.

Comment: Are you sure it was actually deleted from the repository? If you right click on this problematic folder and look at the SVN Log for that folder, does any history show up?

Comment: @Chris All the log entries involving that folder have been replaced with `This is an empty revision for padding.` so I would say so.

Comment: You may need to do another dump filter and [`--drop-empty-revs`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html)

Comment: @Chris I specifically don't want the revisions renumbered, so that's not an option. Also I can't see how it would help. The folder is **gone** from the repository. It's just the working copy that still has it cached.

Comment: The problem is that if you have done a delete and an update, instead of allowing SVN to do the delete for you, it will recreate the directory because it needs something there to delete.  To get around this, create another revision and then just do an update without deleting.  Let SVN do the deletion for you.  Alternatively, set the working copy to an earlier revision and then do an update.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem when messing around with old revision in the repository.

Tortoise default is to enable log caching, so it probably isn't checking the repository for changes to old revisions, therefore restoring the folder.

Try clearing the various cache in tortoise/settings/saved data menu and try again deleting the folder and updating. (should be the one called "Log message (Show log dialog)")